# NodeJS Oboe not sending request body to PHP server

Tags: php, json, node.js, http, oboe.js

I'm trying to get Oboe to send some data with the request, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my simple test script, I have also included a request.js example which works fine:

```
// Doesn't work
var oboe = require('oboe');
oboe({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8440/oboe.php',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        foo: 'bar',
    }),
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('oboe', data);
});

// Works
var request = require('request');
request({
    json: true,
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8440/oboe.php',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        foo: 'bar',
    }),
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('request', body);
});
```

This outputs:

```
$ node test.js
oboe { get: [], post: [], body: '' }
request { get: [], post: [], body: '"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"' }
```

And my simple PHP file for testing:

```
<?php
die(json_encode([
    'get' => $_GET,
    'post' => $_POST,
    'body' => file_get_contents('php://input'),
]));
```

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out. Seems its required to send the `Content-Length` header.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    foo: 'bar',
});
oboe({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8440/oboe.php',
    body: data,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
    },
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('oboe', data);
});
```